# Retrieve a single value from json output?

Tags: python, json, http, curl

I have json output from a curl command where I want to get one value and cannot figure out how to do it.  I'm trying to get the "X-Subject-Token" as seen below.

Reading similar answers I found I could use `json.load(sys.stdin)['X-Subject-Token']'`. I tried to run the snippet below...

```
$ curl -v -s -X POST https://host.com:13000/v3/auth/tokens?nocatalog \
       -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
       -d '{\
            "auth": {\
                "identity": {\
                    "methods": [\
                        "password"\
                    ],\
                    "password": {\
                        "user": {\
                            "domain": {\
                                "name": "'"$OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME"'"\
                            },\
                            "name": "'"$OS_USERNAME"'",\
                            "password": "'"$OS_PASSWORD"'"\
                        }\
                    }\
                },\
                "scope": {\
                    "project": {\
                        "domain": {\
                            "name": "'"$OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME"'"\
                        },\
                        "name": "'"admin"'"\
                    }\
                }\
            }\
        }' | \
    python -m json.tool | \
    python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['X-Subject-Token']'
```

...which gives me the error below:

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'X-Subject-Token'
```

Tried to replace double quotes for single quotes...

```
print json.load(sys.stdin)["X-Subject-Token"]'
```

...to get a different error:

```
NameError: name 'X' is not defined.
```

This is a snippet of the output I'm trying to extract from:

```
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 245
> 

} [data not shown]
* upload completely sent off: 245 out of 245 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< X-Subject-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
< Vary: X-Auth-Token
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 489
```

How can I get `X-Subject-Token`  ?

I have also tried grep and awk which I have a bit more experience with but Python seemed to be the cleanest.

Comment: Can you show the JSON data?

Comment: Are you aware that `X-Subject-Token` is a response header and not part of any JSON?

Comment: The data you show isn't valid JSON. What gets output from `python -n json.tool`?

Comment: Why not use `python` `requests` library to do this whole thing in Python? That way, you'd have access to the returned content as well as all the HTTP headers, etc.

Comment: @jwodder @scnerd  Several domain areas that I'm trying to learn here.  Mostly OpenStack and the API, so I stumbled across the Python example and went with it.   I will look for `python requests` examples and see if I can work it out.  Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X-Subject-Token is a http header in the response. You can use curl's `--include` flag to print the response headers to stdout. Then you simply extract it using for example awk.

```
curl --include -v -s -X POST https://host.com:13000/v3/auth/tokens?nocatalog |\
[ more options ] |\
awk '/X-Subject-Token/ { print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

It really seems to be the case pointed by @jwodder: `X-Subject-Token` is not part of the JSON, but one of the HTTP headers.

When you make an HTTP request, the response comes with a body and a series of headers. The headers are important for the server and the browser properly communicate; the body is the info we usually want. Since headers are *generally* (but not always) relevant only for the server and browser, `curl` by default gives us only the body. Here I'll use some random JSON as an example:

```
$ curl -X GET https://pastebin.com/raw/S5bxekgg
{"foo": "bar", "a": 2}
```

The body is so relevant you even believe the information you need is in it - but it is not! It is in the headers. In this case, we need `curl` to give us the headers as well. It is easy, we only need to give it the `-i` option:

```
$ curl -i -X GET https://pastebin.com/raw/S5bxekgg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 May 2018 23:12:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d570bd74e5f34b1ef0d5fe4658ba5e0461525734756; expires=Tue, 07-May-19 23:12:36 GMT; path=/; domain=.pastebin.com; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: public, max-age=1801
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
CF-Cache-Status: HIT
Expires: Mon, 07 May 2018 23:42:37 GMT
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 41775f564ca44bbd-GRU

{"foo": "bar", "a": 2}
```

Now we have much more information! Alas, my example does not contain the `X-Subject-Token` header you want, so I'll use another header: `X-XSS-Protection`.

It is not in the JSON, though; how do we get it? Well, it is even easier: use shell! Personally, I'd grep for the header I want:

```
$ curl --silent -i -X GET https://pastebin.com/raw/S5bxekgg | grep X-XSS-Protection
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Once I have it, I'd use `cut` to take out the value:

```
$ curl --silent -i -X GET https://pastebin.com/raw/S5bxekgg | grep X-XSS-Protection | cut -d: -f2
1; mode=block
```

And it is only one of the alternatives! We do not even need Python!

So, if my assumption is correct, the problem is not Python, is that you confused HTTP response headers with HTTP response body. If you're dealing with a lot of concepts, it may be a bit messy, but nothing that practice cannot solve ;)